# C#: (error CS1526: A new expression requires an argument list or (), [], or {} after type) How do I fix this?

Tags: c#

`using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MainCamera : MonoBehaviour

```
public GameObject player;
private Vector3 pov = new Vector3(0, 6, -8);

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void LateUpdate()
{
    //Player POV

   transform.position = player.transform.position + new pov;
```

`

Comment: What do you want to express with `new pov`? If you want to refer to the field `pov`, just remove the `new`.

Answer (score 1):

`pov` is an instance of a Vector3 type.

`new` is a reserved keyword used to create new instances of types. So it is meaningless to call `new` on an already instanciated type.

If your intent is adding two instances of `Vector3` together, you just need to remove `new` before `pov`.

```cs
transform.position = player.transform.position + pov;
```

Below is an explanation of the error message.

What is your intent? The compiler doesn't know.

It responds as if you were trying to effectively create an instance of a type named `pov`.

Instance creation involves the reserved keyword `new`, followed by the type and either `(`, `[`, or `{` depending on the circumstances.

Here are a few examples

```cs
var AnniversaryDate = new Datetime();
```

Inside the parenthesis you can pass arguments, like:

```cs
var AnniversaryDate = new Datetime(1990, 11, 07);
```

Array creation

```cs
var Ages = new int[]
{
    35,
    67,
    13
};
```

Empty collection creation

```cs
var Ages= new List<int>();
```

Collection creation and initialization

```cs
var Ages= new List<int>
{
    35,
    67,
    13
};
```

Type with setable public properties

```cs
var John= new Person
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Smith",
    Age = 67
};
```

This explains the message from the compiler:

```
error CS1526: A new expression requires an argument list or (), [], or {} after type
```

The examples above do not cover all possibilities. It can even depends on the version of C# you are using.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator

Comment: I Just named the thing pov as in Perspective I didnt know that pov was a code XD

Comment: Im trying to get the camera to follow my vechicle I removed the pov and changed it to another name but it still shows error CS1526: A new expression requires an argument list or (), [], or {} after type. Im using 1.23.16 in VS code

Comment: I don't understand your comments. `pov` is variable you created, so how can you write "I didn't know that pov was a code"? What do you mean by "a code"? What does mean "I removed the pov and changed it to another name?" If by "code" you mean "C# reserved keyword" then you are mistaken, `pov` is not a reserved keyword, `new` is.

Comment: I just started with Unity and IDK how to fix that error how can I  fix that Im trying to make my camera follow the object without it moving with the obejct everytime it turns.

Comment: Maybe you should try to ask a new question, stating exactly what you want to achieve, with a correct articulation of your ideas, giving the complete context, with the keyword Unity? The title should not be about the error you received. You should not be worried by this error now, its meaning should be clear now for you. If it isn't, you really need to brush up your fondamentals before trying to go further.

Comment: Also be careful to explain your problem as best as you can. For instance, you wrote in the previous comment  "make my camera follow the object without it moving with the obejct everytime it turns". This makes absolutly no sense to me. You have a camera, and an object, and you want them both moving, but without moving? What is "it" the object, the camera, something else? Please take your time to really explain clearly what is your problem.